# Mapping template to use for setting post body to body property of APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am learning AWS API Gateway with Lambda non-proxy integration. I have a few questions?
1) Can I use APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent as the input event for Lambda non-proxy integration?
2) Let's say I have a Class 'SomeBean' with just one property 'name' which I want to sent in post body. How can I specify the mapping template to map the JSON object from the post body to 'body' property of APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent. I tried the following and nothing seems working. 
{"body": $input.body}, {"body" : $input.json('$')}, {"body" : $input.path('$')}
3) Also what should be the format of the request payload ? I tried {"name":"myName"}

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advane.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access the headers and body of the request, then use **API Gateway Lambda Proxy Integration**. This will encapsulate the request to an event object which you use to access all the information of the request.

For e.g. if you are using Java, then use the following Lambda handler.

```
public class App implements RequestHandler<APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent, APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent>{

....

   @Override
    public APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent handleRequest(APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent request, Context context) {
```